# What opportunities are there to write casual articles in math?

Tags: publications, writing, publishability, outreach

I am wondering how to find good opportunities in editorials that publish work to educate younger readers and invite them to be curious about mathematics. For context, I have recently produced many interesting results regarding how the number π pertains to Lebesgue spaces and have accompanied this work with many enjoyable plots. I am fairly certain that the work I've produced is not something worthy of traditional publications. However, I thought it would still be a great topic for a younger audience to write about. I have considered starting a blog, however, I am hesitant as I do not think it will sufficiently reach many people. I know that there are mathematics magazines—and even more broadly scholastic/educational magazines—that aim to engage younger minds (maybe 16 to 25-year-olds) in mathematics. Given that there do exist these magazines, how would one go about judging which avenues of publication/general dissemination are the best fit for this work?

Comment: Ah, young people these days, with their nightclubs and loud music and Lebesgue spaces...

Comment: 'Mathematics' and 'casual' have no intersecting space. More seriously, there are some publications on recreational mathematics and on teaching mathematics. Take a look.

Comment: I'm not sure how "casual" applies here

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I am using casual in a way that describes how I might enjoy reading an article about glaciers or tectonic plates despite having no real in-depth knowledge of geology. I suppose I am classifying academic literature into two categories: Technical (think Elsevier or Springer) and Casual (types of articles that are meant to captivate an audience—in this case a young audience—or educate a lay audience). Perhaps there are better words than causal but I think the point of the post remains just as clear even with a better synonym.

Comment: if you do start a blog, you might find Summer of Math exposition (https://some.3b1b.co/) interesting. It is a competition for math explainers which mostly serves as a platform to discover them

Comment: @DG_researcher Yes, the post is clear; my suggestion was to align the title with the post, rather than clarify the body. Maybe this is a math-specific terminology, but I think the title would better fit the body if it included your  mention of younger readers